# React setState and interval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I don't understand why `currentExpVal` is always has a value of `0`. It means the interval doesn't stop. Could anybody explain it?

I want to have a smoothly updating counter during interval until it's not 10 (for example).

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./Experience.module.scss";

type Props = {};

export const Experience: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const expValueRef = useRef(10);
  const [currentExpVal, setCurrentExpVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      // console.info(currentExpVal, expValueRef.current)
      if (currentExpVal < expValueRef.current) {
        console.info(currentExpVal, expValueRef.current);
        setCurrentExpVal((prev) => {
          return prev + 1;
        });
      } else {
        console.info("clear");
        clearInterval(intervalRef);
      }
    }, 1500);
  }, []);

  // currentExpVal is not updated within if (currentExpVal < expValueRef.current)

  return (
    <div className={styles["exp-wrapper"]}>
      {currentExpVal}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: [Please include code as text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Because your `useEffect` doesn't have `currentExpVal` as a dependency, so the effect function captures a stale value. You would need to add it as a dependency (not optimal because the interval would then be recreated over and over) or ref-box the state atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your effect runs only once due to the empty dependency array `[]`, so inside your effect `currentExpVal` references the very first value of the state variable, that's why it's always 0.

I would split the work in 2 effects, one to init the interval and another one to check if the limit is reached.

```
const expValueRef = useRef(10);
const [currentExpVal, setCurrentExpVal] = useState(0);
const interValId = useRef();

// init and clean interval
useEffect(() => {
  interValId.current = setInterval(() => {
    setCurrentExpVal(prevValue => prevValue + 1);
  }, 1500);

  // clean interval when component is unmounted
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId.current);
}, [intervalId]);

// check if the limit is reached
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentExpVal >= expValueRef.current) {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  }
}, [currentExpVal]);
```

I suggest you to use [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) to prevent this kind of error. It would have warned you that you forgot to pass `currentExpVal` in the effect dependencies.

Comment: Okay, great, thanks, man

Comment: But one strange case, if I put console.log to the first effect it is called twice. hmm

Comment: I found the problem. It was an issue with Strict Mode. Strict mode for dev calls useEffect twice

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is a closure one, which occurs especially when used with `setInterval`. When the `useEffect` hook is run for the first time, the current value of `currentExpVal` is captured and is 0 at that point. Inside the `setInterval`, this value never gets updated; hence you always see the 0 value.

You can use the `setCurrentExpVal` callback to access the latest state. You already use that but you're comparing the wrong values. Instead of comparing `currentExpVal` and `expValueRef.current`, you can compare the current state within the updater function.

The solution above that @Olivier gave is also valid. Here is the other one:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
        setCurrentExpVal((prev) => {
            console.info(prev, expValueRef.current);

            // If the previous value is less than the target, increment and return.
            if (prev < expValueRef.current) {
                return prev + 1;
            } else {
                console.info('clear');
                clearInterval(intervalRef);  // If not, clear the interval.
                return prev;  // Return the current value without modification.
            }
        });
    }, 1500);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef);
}, []);
```